# What are real life use cases of literal types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, literals

I am getting to learn about literal types and I am struggling to find much real life use cases for them. The only one I can think of is their usage for modeling discriminated unions.

The problem is that, most of the time, my program works with variables and not literals, which makes literal types not as useful as they are shown in the examples I am seeing online.

For example, the sort of code that is used to explain literal type could take the following form:

```
declare function delete(confirmation: "yes" | "no")
```

but the thing is, in real life, the confirmation would have been parsed and stored in a variable first, which will make it unusable in calling the `delete` function

```
let dodelete = ... // sets this based on computation to "yes" or "no" or just anything
delete(dodelete) // nope does not work
```

The `dodelete` will probably not be set directly in the code but either from a use input or server request.

This I think make literal types less usable as they are presented, or perhaps I am missing other use cases?

Apart from modeling discriminated unions, does anyone know of any other use cases for literal types?

Answer (score 1):

I used Literal types to make a hint for whoever uses this method to choose between these values more than set a specific type.

Check the image below.

[image]

Comment: but this only works, or forces the caller to call the method with string literals. Putting the value, even though it might be right, into a variable first wont compile. I am not sure that is a good thing. Imagine a scenario where one need to call the function multiple times with the same value. Such is a situation where one might think of putting the value into a variable first. But using literal type makes that impossible.